# Differentiating a Brownian distribution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So, I have the following Brownian distribution that models the number of molecules arriving at some distance $d$. If we take the derivative of  the given equation w.r.t to the time $t$ we obtain the time taken to propagate the molecules to the distance $d$. Is my differentiation correct?
$$N(t)= \frac{{VQ}}{(4\pi{Dt})^{3/2}} {\exp\left(-\frac{d^2}{4{Dt}}\right)}$$ 
if I take the derivative of the above equation and set it to $0$, then
$$\frac d{dt}N(t)=\frac d{dt}\left(\frac{{VQ}}{(4\pi{Dt})^{3/2}} {\exp\left(-\frac{d^2}{4{Dt}}\right)}\right) = 0$$

$$=\frac{{VQ}}{(4\pi{D})^{3/2}} \frac d{dt}\left(\frac{1}{{t}^{3/2}} {\exp\left(-\frac{d^2}{4{Dt}}\right)}\right) = 0$$
Next using product rule and transfering $VQ/(4\pi{D})^{3/2}$ on the RHS, 
$$= \frac d{dt}\left(\frac{1}{{t}^{3/2}} \right) {\exp\left(-\frac{d^2}{4{Dt}}\right)} +  \left(\frac{1}{{t}^{3/2}} \right)\frac d{dt}{\exp\left(-\frac{d^2}{4{Dt}}\right)}   = 0$$

$$= \left(\frac{-3}{{2t}^{1/2}} \right) {\exp\left(-\frac{d^2}{4{Dt}}\right)} +  \left(\frac{1}{{t}^{3/2}} \right){\exp\left(-\frac{d^2}{4{Dt}}\right)}\left(\frac{-d^2}{4D}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{t^{1/2}} \right)  = 0$$

After removing the common terms and transfering them to the RHS we are left with,
$$ \frac{3}{2}- \frac{d^2}{4Dt^{3/2}} = 0$$
$$ \frac{3}{2} = \frac{d^2}{4Dt^{3/2}}$$
$$ t^{3/2} = \frac{d^2}{6D}$$

Is this correct? What bothers me is the power of ${3/2}$. I think that should not be there. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There is no $x$ in your function. Are you actually differentiating with respect to $t$?

Comment: Anyway, assuming that you are differentiating w.r.t. $t$, it comes handy to utilize the log-differentiation: $$\frac{N'(t)}{N(t)} = \frac{d}{dt}\log N(t) = \frac{d^2}{4Dt^2} - \frac{3}{2t}. $$ So solving $N'(t) = 0$ gives $t = d^2/6D$. Notice that both sides have the same dimension as well.

Comment: @SangchulLee Oh, sorry I edited $x$ to $t$.

Comment: @SangchulLee That's good to know. It's just that the article from where I found this issue never mentioned taking the log derivative. But this seems legit.